# Laravel whereHas on Many-to-Many relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationships

I have two main tables with relationships many to many and a pivot table.

Model 'Type'

```
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Attribute', 'attribute_type');
    }
```

Model 'Attribute'

```
    public function types()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Type', 'attribute_type');
    }
```

Pivot table 'attribute_type'

```
    Schema::create('attribute_type', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('type_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('types');
        $table->integer('attribute_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('attribute_id')->references('id')->on('attributes');
    });
```

I want to show 5 attributes in random order which belong to the types of id < 10.

```
$attributes = Attribute::whereHas('types', function ($query) {
            $query->where('id', '<', '10');
        })->orderByRaw("RAND()")->limit(5);
```

and for example

```
$attribute->id
```

gives me "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$id"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All you have to do is execute query and get the collection with `get()` method like this:

```
$attributes = Attribute::whereHas('types', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', '<', '10');
    })->orderByRaw("RAND()")->limit(5)
    ->get();
```

Now you are trying to iterate over the query builder which is giving you another query builder as a result of `$attribute`

Comment: also I changed where('id', '<', '10'); to where('type_id', '<', '10');

Answer (score 5):

You have 2 options:

```
$attributes = Attribute::whereHas('types', function ($query) {
            $query->where('types.id', '<', '10');
        })->orderByRaw("RAND()")->limit(5);
```

or

```
$attributes = Attribute::whereHas('types', function ($query) {
            $query->where('attribute_type.type_id', '<', '10');
        })->orderByRaw("RAND()")->limit(5);
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include a short explanation of *how* each of these statements answers the question. This helps to provide context and makes your answer more useful for future readers.